# Passing a pointer to a method and assigning an object to it

Tags: objective-c, pointers, scope

Consider this example:

```
NSMutableArray *aArray;
[Util doSomeMagic:aArray];
[aArray count];

- (void)doSomeMagic:(NSMutableArray *)aArray
{
    if(aArray == NULL)
    {
      aArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [aArray addObject:@"magic"];
    [aArray addObject:@"magic2"];
}
```

The `doSomeMagic:` method will fill in the array. Inside `doSomeMagic:`, I can get the array count correctly, but outside the method, the array remains empty. How can I let the `doSomeMagic:` method change the content that is passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doSomeMagic:` method needs to receive the array by reference, ensuring it modifies the object it receives:

```
- (void)doSomeMagic:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    // for example, let's remove the last element in the array
    [array removeLastObject];
}
```

I'm guessing your `doSomeMagic:` might look like this (which doesn't work because it modifies a copy of the array for scope):

```
- (void)doSomeMagic:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    // for example, let's remove the last element in the array
    [newArray removeLastObject];
}
```

EDIT: I see you've added your `doSomeMagic:` code. You need to understand pass by reference here. Since you call `doSomeMagic:` with a nil array (because you declared `aArray` without setting it to point to anything afterwards), when `doSomeMagic:` runs it assigns a new array to nil, and then the method returns with no visible effect. I suggest changing the code where you call it to:

```
NSMutableArray *aArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[Util doSomeMagic:aArray];
[aArray count];
```

and your `doSomeMagic:` method to:

```
- (void)doSomeMagic:(NSMutableArray *)aArray
{
    [aArray addObject:@"magic"];
    [aArray addObject:@"magic2"];
}
```

Keep in mind that since I am using the class `array` on NSMutableArray, the array returned will be autoreleased after `[aArray count];`. The final code would look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *aArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
[Util doSomeMagic:aArray];
[aArray count];
[aArray release];
```

Comment: I see, is the problem of nil array... Thank u, Alan.

Comment: No problem. For a better understanding of the problem, I suggest you learn the difference between 'pass by reference' and 'pass by value': http://maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered the resulting array is immutable.  You need to pass it by reference

- (BOOL)TweakMe:(NSMultableArray **)o {
  ...
  }

Comment: When I changed the NSMultableArray * to NSMultableArray **, the function I called the o, for example, add an object, it shows me a warning, and saying Instance method not found, what's happen behind the scene?